# Disable Custom Context Menu items in PyQt

Tags: pyqt

So I created a custom context menu, but I want to grey out some of the items in certain rows of my tree widget depending on certain values.  How do I disable items on the menu?

```
myUI.setContextMenuPolicy( Qt.CustomContextMenu )
myMenu = QMenu( "Right Click Menu", myUI )
action = myMenu.addAction( "Item 1" )
action.triggered.connect( someFunction )
```

Answer (score 14):

To disable a menu item, just [disable the `QAction`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#enabled-prop)

```
action.setEnabled(False)
```